# Select change is not effective with in the mouse out function JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I am working on a functionality where in when someone hover on to a block a form appears, I have used mouseover and mouseout functions to show the and hide the form. When we are selecting any option form these selection option, which are flowing out of the block range the form block is disappearing which is a flaw.

**I have written the below jQuery**

```
jQuery(function(){

jQuery(".find-a-doc").mouseout(function(){
        jQuery(".doctor-con").css("display","none");
         });

jQuery(".find-a-doc").mouseover(function(){
        jQuery(".doctor-con").css("display","block");                            
    });

jQuery("#edit-field-department-latest-value").bind("change", function() { 
       alert('Value change to ' + jQuery(this).attr('value'));
    if(jQuery(this).attr('value')>=1)
    {
       jQuery(".doctor-con").css("display","block"); 
    }
    else
{
       jQuery(".doctor-con").css("display","none");
       alert('value selected is less than 1');
}
     });    
   });
```

I want the form block to be displayed when any section is made from the selection box.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first recommend changing to the .on jQuery method (as the bind live and delegate methods are deprecated) and then try binding your mouseout event to both the container and form fields, or possibly just the form fields, if you set up a jsfiddle with your html css and js for this I'll gladly solve it for you.